# Issues with playfab leaderboard

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, playfab

Im having issues with PlayFab, What im trying to do is have the wave number recorded and sent off to the leaderboard when the game is over but I dont know how to connect the wave number to the playfab leaderboard. I have been trying to use this line: `playfabManager.SendLeaderboard(here I have to put an int)`  to send to the leaderboard. This is the code to get the wave number

```cs
EnemyWaveManager.Instance.GetWaveNumber()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Playfab leaderboards are populated based on **player statistics**.
So this means you should update player statistics ([**UpdatePlayerStatistics**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/playfab/client/player-data-management/update-player-statistics?view=playfab-rest)).

If **wave number** is a value common to all players in the game, use instead TitleData to keep that kind of data.

Answer (score 1):

I think Benry got the idea, but I want to add some comments on Title Data. Since the wave number should be the data for ranking in a Leaderboard. It should not be stored in title Data. Title Data is a cached resource, which doesn't support multiple writes at the same time. It is more suitable for global static data. You may check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/playfab/features/data/titledata/quickstart for more details.